# Robot framework, how to check class

Tags: html, selenium, testing, tdd, robotframework

Is there a keyword in Robot Framework to ensure element has a certain class? Something like

`Element should has class    element    className`

Alternatively, I could check if element has a certain attribute with certain value. Former would be more suitable though, as element may contain multiple classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a new keyword via XPath selectors:

```
Element should have class
    [Arguments]  ${element}  ${className}
    Wait until page contains element  ${element}[contains(@class, '${className}')]
```

Or via CSS selectors:

```
Element should have class
    [Arguments]  ${element}  ${className}
    Wait until page contains element  ${element}.${className}
```

`Wait until page contains element` could be replaced by any keyword of your liking to check if the element exists and is visible, such as `Element should be visible`.

Comment: `| FAIL |
Element 'loginButton[contains(@class, 'button-blue')]' did not appear in 5 seconds` even though there is an element with id loginButton and class button-blue. I also presumed the className in first example needs curly braces to evaluate the variable.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen: I forgot the curly braces, sorry for that. It should work as of now. `loginButton` is no valid XPath nor CSS selector, either use `#loginButton` or `//*[@id='loginButton']`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative solution (though the accepted answer's CSS one is quite good), working for any kind of selector strategy:

```
Element should have class
    [Arguments]  ${locator}  ${target value}

    ${class}=       Get Element Attribute  ${locator}@class
    Should Contain  ${class}        ${target value}
```

It can be modified for any other attribute - just substitute the `@class` in `Get Element Attribute` with it (or even, make it an optional argument).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the solutions on this page may suffer from sub-string matches. Checking that the class attribute (e.g. `test-run`) contains a class (e.g. `test`) may pass even though it should fail.

There are a few ways to deal with this, but in the end, I did the following:

```
Element Should Have Class
    [Arguments]                ${locator}               ${class}
    ${escaped}=                Regexp Escape            ${class}
    ${classes}=                Get Element Attribute    ${locator}        class
    Should Match Regexp        ${classes}               \\b${escaped}\\b

Element Should Not Have Class
    [Arguments]                ${locator}               ${class}
    ${escaped}=                Regexp Escape            ${class}
    ${classes}=                Get Element Attribute    ${locator}        class
    Should Not Match Regexp    ${classes}               \\b${escaped}\\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below an example of both ways:

```
    ${temp}=    get element attribute       xpath=/elementpath    class
    should contain        ${temp}   ${ClassName}
```

OR

```
 Wait until page contains element  xpath=/elementpath[contains(@class, '${ClassName}')
```